# Advantages between CXF and JAX-WS standard

Tags: web-services, cxf

I'm new on web service programming, and while I was using simple JAX-WS for my Web services, when I stumbled on CXF. The point is that I don't know exactly what CXF (or other framework for WS, but specifically CXF) adds to my project... can someone explain to me?

Thank you very much,
Yuri.